# Angular2 Lazy loading Fails with a shared module

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I've created an `AccountModule` that successfully lazy loads, but when I add my `SharedModule` to the `AccountModule` my app seems to forget all of my eagerly loaded modules and I get the error:

> Component FoodComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Where `FoodComponent` is an eagerly loaded component that both loaded and rendered correctly before calling for the `AccountModule` via lazy load. If I remove that component fro the app, then the next eagerly loaded component send the same issue. What is it about my `SharedModule` that is making this happen?

**shared.module.ts**

```
// ... imports ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [     
    CalNavComponent, 
    IngredientsListComponent, 
  ],
  exports: [ 
    MaterialModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    CommonModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,

    CalNavComponent, 
    IngredientsListComponent, 
  ],
  providers: [ 
    UserDataService 
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**account.module.ts**

```
// ... imports ...

const routerConfig: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AccountComponent
}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, /* Works fine when this is gone */
    RouterModule.forChild(routerConfig)
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AccountComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    AccountComponent
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { } // adding 'default' results in "cannot find module at app/features/account/account.module"
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'food', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/account/account.module#AccountModule'
    // component: AccountComponent, /* This worked fine*/
  },
  {
    path: 'food',
    component: FoodComponent
  },
  //... more paths
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Why would you export `AppRoutingModule` from shared? Not saying that is the issue, but it is very suspect code.

Comment: I think I've followed an out dated Routing module tutorial. I've solve the issue using ModuleWithProviders instead and adding it to `AppModule` alone. I'll put together the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was Following an outdated `AppRoutingModule` tutorial. Instead of a traditional `NgModule` module I switched to a `ModuleWithProviders` module.

**account.routing.ts**

```
import { AccountComponent } from './account.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AccountComponent
}]

export const AccountRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

**account.module.ts**

```
import { AccountRouting } from './account.routing';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AccountComponent } from '../account/account.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    AccountRouting
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AccountComponent
  ],
  exports:[
    AccountComponent
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { }
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { FoodComponent } from './features/food/food.component';
// import { AccountComponent } from './features/account/account.component';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'calendar',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'app/features/account/account.module#AccountModule'
    //component: AccountComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'food',
    component: FoodComponent
  },
  //... more routes
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```